# How do I declare a pointer to an array of Class objects, within the private members of a DIFFERENT Class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, private

My aggravation with this problem has been compounded largely with the heavy use of vector as the cure-all in all the other solutions.

Let me preface this problem by saying that I am REQUIRED to use pointers, as annoying as they may be, to solve this problem. I may not use vector as it has not been covered in our course material.

I am used to the following format for declaring a pointer to an array.

```
int* numbers;
numbers= new int[10];
```

Bingo, I just created an array with ten elements that can store ints. Woot!

Now, I'm trying to create a pointer, to an array of objects, but not just any objects!

I have two classes. One called Account and the other called Transaction. Within the private members of my Account class I need to make "A pointer to an array of Transactions, used to keep track of all of the transactions made for that account" Why am I doing it this way? Beat the absolute hell outta me, these are the instructions I was given and I just copy pasted them from within the Account private member section.

Here is how I have attempted this:

```
    class Account
{

    private:
        static const int MAX_TRANS = 100;
        int mAcctType;
        int mNumTrans;
        double mAcctBal;
        std::string mAcctName;

    Transaction* transaction;
    transaction = new Transaction[MAX_TRANS];

    void allocate();
    void deallocate();
    void copy(const Account& account);
public: 
    static const int CHECKING = 0;
    static const int SAVINGS = 1;
```

I can't understand what I've done wrong but I get several error messages.

First in this section:

```
`   Transaction* transaction;
    transaction = new Transaction[MAX_TRANS];`
```

I get the red squiggly underneath transaction, the pointer I'm now trying to instantiate, which states "the declaration has no storage class or type specifier".Well why is it not of the Transaction type?

Next I get the following error messages.

```
C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   
C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Here's the complete code for my transaction class:

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
#define TRANSACTION_H

#include"Account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Transaction
{
private:
    int mTransType;
    double mTransAmt;

public:
    static const int DEPOSIT = 1;
    static const int WITHDRAW = 0;
    Transaction();
    Transaction(int mTransType, double mTransAmt);
    int GetTransType() { return mTransType; };
    double GetTransAmt() { return mTransAmt; };
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& out, Transaction transaction);
};

#endif
```

I can't understand why we're doing it this way, I'm sure it seems absurd to many of you.

All I need to know is the proper syntax for declaring a pointer to an array of objects within the private members of a different class.

Comment: please dont put too many things into one question. Why is `transaction = new Transaction[MAX_TRANS];` not in the "complete code" ? Do you have different versions of the code? We need to see only one

Comment: `transaction = new Transaction[MAX_TRANS];` can't appear in the member declaration area of your class. It needs to be in a function(hint: or a constructor). Frankly, it's unclear why that's dynamic in the first place, since it size is fixed, and reasonable small.

Comment: also `static const int MAX_TRANS = 100;` does not appear in the "complete code". Is the size always fixed, or is this static member just your attempt to get it working somehow? If not, what is the size? Should it be passed to the constructor?

Comment: uh sorry, I misread your question and missed the fact that `Account` and `Transaction` are two seperate classes

Comment: "transaction = new Transaction[MAX_TRANS]; can't appear in the member declaration area of your class. "


Fine then. My instructions tell me specifically to create "A pointer to an array of Transactions, used to keep track of all of the transactions made for that account". 

Can I at least do this?

Comment: Solution: `Transaction* transaction = nullptr;` creates a pointer in the private members of Account. Next,  I use Account::allocate() to dynamically allocate a new array of transaction objects: `{transaction = new Transaction[Account::MAX_TRANS];}`

So to summarize, you create a pointer of one class type within the private members of a different class type. Then, you allocate the array using your inherited class pointer to create an array of objects as a member of a different class. 

Ty @WhozCraig for explaining I couldn't allocate in the private member area.

Comment: Since you have to write the code to do your own array book keeping, can you write your own simplified vector class anyway? Then the class does the book keeping and you're not throwing pointers around your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I need to know is the proper syntax for declaring a pointer to an array of objects within the private members of a different class.

To be honest, I don't know if something like this exists, "a pointer to an array". Here:

```
Transaction* transaction;
```

`transaction` is a pointer to a single `Transaction`. If you want this to be the first element of a dynamically allocated array, then that is your buisness. You have to do all the bookkeeping: Allocate right size, reallocate if needed, respect the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and last but not least make sure you are not leaking memory. All this is a nightmare, it is error prone and other than for torturing students there is no practical use in doing all that manually (`std::vector` or smart pointers should be used for dynamic arrays). It might seem like splitting hairs, but it is important to realize that `transaction` really does point to a single object and if you need more you are on your own.

The problem with `transaction = new Transaction[MAX_TRANS];` is that you cannot assign to a member in the class declaration outside of a function. You could use the constructor to allocate the array. However, if anyhow you always allocate an array of fixed size, then there is no need for dynamic allocation in the first place:

```
class Account {
private:
    static const int MAX_TRANS = 100;
    Transaction transaction[MAX_TRANS];
    // ... more ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm going to update with my fix.

Comment: The instructions were obtuse. It didn't all need to be done in one step, it should have read: Create pointer. Allocate pointer elsewhere. Thank you for the help.